# How to pass over an authentication window from within Bash Terminal?

Tags: bash, authentication, curl

Suppose there are some web sites that require people to type in his or her username and/or password to pass through the authentication dialog to get the actual contents behind it. When people encounter such web sites on a browser he or she can type in his or her username and/or password to pass through the authentication. However, is it feasible to verify it from within Terminal?

The content there is a single zip file, and I was able to download it using curl and `-u` option to specify my username. However, it still requires me to type in my password to pass through the authentication, and I would like to know how to automatically go through it using my password, without being prompted to type in my password, since I have to download it every day, and want to use my bash script to achieve it.

I use OS X 10.9.2 and I would like to access it from within my Terminal. I have both of my username and password on the authentication for sure. I might be interested to know the most secure way possible to pass through the verification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use `curl` for this, just change the argument you give for `-u` to include the password:

```
curl -u username:password http://www.website.com/content/file.zip
```

Obviously this requires storing your password in plaintext in your script, which is not ideal for security. If you have SSH access to the server in question, you can create a private/public key pair, then use the public key to log into the server without a password being required (and download the file using `scp`), which would ideal from a security point of view.

Comment: Awesome! As to the SSH access, it's necessary to first ask an administrator of the site to use SSH, right? In other words, it cannot be done unless the administrator of the site implements the SSH access, right?

Comment: Yes, you will need access to the server itself via the configured SSH port, as well as a shell login.